# What are the long term effects of Dexedrine (for adult ADD)?

Tags: lasting-effects-duration, energy, add-adhd, amphetamine, neuroscience

Dexedrine is a common treatment for ADD in adults.  It is a stimulant that helps with focus and engagement in their work.

But it is an amphetamine and thus has potential for chemical dependence.

Missing a dose or stopping can lead to withdrawal symptoms like depression, anxiety, fatigue, irritability.

Therefore missing a dose may leave an individual feeling less happy, less energetic

Questions:

- The longer one takes Dexedrine, will one become more reliant on it for energy/happiness/motivation?
- Will the side-effects of not missing a dose get worse over the years?
- Are any of these effects permanent?

Comment: This is probably something you should be **discussing with your doctor**. Regarding your question, it is very personal in my eyes and likely to get closed. Is it possible to make it more general (i.e. remove the personal background and changing from *will I* to *will one*. I have proposed an edit.

Comment: I propose this as a clearer and less medical-advice-y way to ask it!  Please feel free to revert.